# Loop multidimensional array and display the data in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to loop an array and display the data, kinda like an image slider. I want it to use '0' then after 3 seconds display '1' etc etc, then loop back to the start.

```
    var people = {
   0: {
     'name': '<span class="name">Name</span>',
     'desc': '<span>Some text about this person.</span>',
     'imgSrc': "<div class='team-img></div>"
   },

   1: {
     'name': '<span class="name">Name</span>',
     'desc': '<span>Some text about this person.</span>',
     'imgSrc': "<div class='team-img></div>"
    },
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    setInterval(function() {
    $(".name").replaceWith(array[i]['name']);
        $("article").replaceWith(array[i]['desc']);
        $(".team-img").replaceWith(array[i]['imgSrc']);
    }, 3000)

});
```

Comment: What is the question or problem? Curious why you need to replace whole elements and don't scale back the data to just text and just update that

Comment: Where do you set `i`?

Comment: `people` is an object, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array rather than an object. Then you can compare `i` to `people.length` to know that you should loop around.

You also had a bunch of errors. You were replacing `article` with `span`, so the next time wouldn't find the `article`. And you were using `array[i]` instead of `people[i]`.

```js
var people = [
   {
    'name': '<span class="name">Name 1</span>',
    'desc': '<article>Some text about this Person 1.</article>',
    'imgSrc': "<div class='team-img'>Image 1</div>"
   },

   {
    'name': '<span class="name">Name 2</span>',
    'desc': '<article>Some text about that person 2.</article>',
    'imgSrc': "<div class='team-img'>Image 2</div>"
   }
];


$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;

  setInterval(function() {
    $(".name").replaceWith(people[i].name);
    $("article").replaceWith(people[i].desc);
    $(".team-img").replaceWith(people[i].imgSrc);
    i = (i+1) % people.length;
  }, 3000)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="name">No name yet</span>
<br>
<article>No article</article>
<div class="team-img">No image</div>
```